# JSONP Call not entering .map function in Angular service

Tags: angular, rxjs, jsonp

Writing a service for an angular project that connects to an external API using the JSONP get request from the HttpClient. I'm not getting any error messages but the callback function is not executing.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

export class CoursesAPIService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getData() {
        var url = 'http://web-app.usc.edu/web/soc/api/classes/&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK'
        console.log("calling: " + url)

        return this.http.jsonp(url, "callback")
           .pipe(map(data => {
               console.log("Inside map")

               console.log(data)
           })
        )
    }
}
```

I am able to call the function just fine and the "Calling + url" console log is working fine but "Inside map" is not printing.

Comment: Do you ever subscribe to the Observable returned from `getData()`?

Comment: This has solved my problem, thank you! I am now getting a different error but progress is progress.